# Missing file .mex error on a newer matlab version

Tags: matlab, mex, force-feedback

I have a .mex code that properly works on Matlab 2012b (32bit).
However, I would like to make it work also on Matlab 2019b (64bit).
When I run it in Matlab 2019, even though the directory is introduced in the path, the error that I get is: 
Missing file directm.mex 
Have somebody encountered this kind of problem?
Specifically, the toolbox is "forcefeedback toolbox"
https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4939-force-feedback-toolbox-for-matlab-simulink

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your MEX-file is a 32-bit binary. You cannot combine it with a 64-bit binary (the newer MATLAB program). The only way to get this to work is to recompile the MEX-file with the newer MATLAB. Unfortunately it looks like this File Exchange submission doesn't come with the sources to the MEX-file. So you are, unfortunately, out of luck.